# Constants vs. objects instantiated on demand - which is optimal?

Tags: ruby, oop, optimization, memory-management, garbage-collection

Take the following method (written in Ruby but this question could be applied to most OO languages)

```
# Getter method which returns an alert
def alertView
  _alertView = AlertView.new
  _alertView.title = "This is the title"
  _alertView.body = "This is the body of my alert"
  _alertView
end
```

Suppose this method is called regularly throughout the lifecycle of an application. The title and body attribute strings would be instantiated as new objects each time.

To optimise this, we could do the following:

```
ALERT_TITLE = "This is the title"
ALERT_BODY  = "This is the body of my alert"

# Getter method which returns an alert
def alertView
  _alertView = AlertView.new
  _alertView.title = ALERT_TITLE
  _alertView.body = ALERT_BODY
  _alertView
end
```

This way, the `ALERT_TITLE` and `ALERT_BODY` strings are only instantiated once, when the class is defined, and then reused throughout the application's lifecycle.

My question is: is the second approach optimal?  While it means less work for the garbage collector and probably more stable memory use, it would also mean that the application is taking more memory all the time, rather than freeing objects that are not currently required.  I'm torn between applying this to all of the constant strings within my application or not applying this approach at all and defining each string as and when required.

A third approach would be to use class variables but the only advantage this offers over the second approach is that the variables are lazy-loaded.

```
# Getter method which returns an alert
def alertView
  _alertView = AlertView.new
  _alertView.title = @@alert_title ||= "This is the title"
  _alertView.body = @@alert_body ||= "This is the body of my alert"
  _alertView
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two variants above are not entirely equal. Observe:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > A = 'a'
 => "a" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > s1 = A # constant assignment
 => "a" 
1.9.3p194 :003 > s2 = A
 => "a" 
1.9.3p194 :004 > s1 << 'b'
 => "ab" 
1.9.3p194 :005 > s2 # you changed s2 as well!
 => "ab" 
1.9.3p194 :006 > s1 = 'a' # literal assignment
 => "a" 
1.9.3p194 :007 > s2 = 'a'
 => "a" 
1.9.3p194 :008 > s1 << 'b'
 => "ab" 
1.9.3p194 :009 > s2 # s2 stayed the same.
 => "a"
```

When two variables are assigned the same constant, there still is **just one** instance of the string in memory. When you assign a literal string, every variable has its own instance in memory (this doesn't apply to symbols, which you correctly noted in another comment). So, everything depends on what you want to achieve (or avoid), how many instances you create and so on.

If the question is really about strings, as in your example, I would say that you stop caring about efficiency and start caring about code readability, as all these are **tiny tiny fractions** of the memory available to your programs nowadays.

So, I'd advice to do whatever you consider cleaner, from programmer's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in C# and Java, anyway, these would be equally optimal. Because of something called "string interning", the compiler recognizes that you're instantiating the same string each time, so it will give each new AlertView object the same two object references for the two strings you're using.

Now, Ruby being an interpreted language, and... not C# or Java... I'm not sure whether or not it does this. So, hopefully someone else will also answer. But my first guess would be that it does implement string internalization- simply because, even though it's interpreted, it should still be able to easily recognize string constants when it encounters them and handle them the same (optimized) way other languages handle them.

Comment: A quick search revealed that Ruby's answer to string interning are it's symbols. `"hello".object_id != "hello".object_id` but `:hello.object_id == :hello.object_id`

Comment: In ruby strings have a `intern` method, which returns a symbol.

Comment: Ruby doesn't internally intern strings the way e.g. Java does, simply because it can't do that without breaking it's semantics. In Java and C#, strings are immutable, i.e. each time you perform an operation on a string, you get a new object back while in Ruby, you can change a string instance in place. Now, if Ruby would intern arbitrary string objects, you would get random results on all on-place operations. As several people already said, you can use symbols instead which are basically immutable strings. It is up to the programmer to decide when which type can be used.